Creating a folder on Google Drive using GoogleCredentials
I have the following function to authorize access to Google Drive in order to create a folder on Google Drive using GoogleCredentials.
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0")
implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.5.0")
implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev20240521-2.0.0")

implementation("com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.26.0")

// Google Sign in
fun signIn(context: Context) {

    val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder().setRequestedScopes(SCOPES).build()

    Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context as Activity).authorize(authorizationRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->

            if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {

                // Access needs to be granted by the user
                val pendingIntent = authorizationResult.pendingIntent
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                        context, pendingIntent!!.intentSender, 999, null, 0, 0, 0, null
                    )
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    Log.i("@@@", "Authorization failed: " + e.message)
                }

            } else {

                // Access authorized, do stuff
                Log.i("@@@", "Access granted")

                val token = authorizationResult.accessToken
                val credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(token, null))
                val requestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

                val googleDriveService = Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), //NetHttpTransport(),
                    GsonFactory(), requestInitializer
                )
                    .setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build()

                Log.i("@@@", googleDriveService.toString())

                try {
                    // Create folder on Google Drive
                    // Folder metadata
                    val folderMetadata =
                        File().setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
                            .setParents(listOf(ROOT))
                            .setName(FOLDER_NAME).setStarred(true)
                            .setFolderColorRgb("#FF0000")       // Red color

                    // Create folder
                    googleDriveService.files().create(folderMetadata).execute()     // This crashes the app, error msg: null

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("@@@", e.message.toString())
                }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("@@@", "Failed to authorize", e) }
}

Everything seems to be fine as far as syntax, however the folder is not created and after testing, the following: googleDriveService.files().create(folderMetadata).execute() causes a crash, the error message is "null"
I call the above function from a button's onClick = { signIn(context) }
I would really appreciate any help with this, I've been struggling for weeks with it. Thanks.
Edit:
In my AndroidManifest.xml I have:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

The full log of the exception is:
null
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1675)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:506)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:616)
at mdc.auMenu.ui.account.GDriveKt.signIn$lambda$0(GDrive.kt:98)
at mdc.auMenu.ui.account.GDriveKt.$r8$lambda$p_pBQS_xClgWTOPLtc5ZI1mWzwo(Unknown Source:0)
at mdc.auMenu.ui.account.GDriveKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at mdc.auMenu.ui.account.GDriveKt.signIn$lambda$1(GDrive.kt:54)
at mdc.auMenu.ui.account.GDriveKt.$r8$lambda$z9STuCnUdP6vzHpOxi9Ibd4ex84(Unknown Source:0)
at mdc.auMenu.ui.account.GDriveKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onSuccess(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.1.0:1)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

It would help if you logged the exception instead of just e.message.toString().

Indeed. I'll post the log below.

With the new information provided by you supplying the Exception trace we can see this:
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1675) at...

So this is not Google Drive at all - you are not getting that far - the Android OS is refusing you access to make a Network access on the main thread of the application.
Take a look at this Question/Answer and way you can offload the task to a background thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14443056/1847378

Thanks, this did it. Strangely, I didn't have this issue with the deprecated method.

I am using Google Drive API on the server side (Kotlin on a JVM, not Kotlin on  Android), so I cannot test this, but try changing:
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(token, null))

to
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes
val DRIVE_SCOPES: List<String> = arrayOf(DriveScopes.DRIVE).toList()

val credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(token, null))
                     .createScoped(DRIVE_SCOPES)


Thanks for answering, unfortunately no change.

As @k314159 says - is there an Exception?  Also do you know you have permissions to Write on the Drive/parent folder?

On Google Cloud Console the scopes are set correctly. During the authoriation process, I see the account pickup pop up, then the scopes authrization. In my code I have this:
const val APPDATA_SCOPE = DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA
const val FILE_SCOPE = DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE
private val SCOPES = listOf(Scope(APPDATA_SCOPE), Scope(FILE_SCOPE))
private val ACCESS_SCOPES = listOf(APPDATA_SCOPE, FILE_SCOPE)

Using the deprecated GoogleSignIn it worked, I want to use a current approach. FYI: I added the exception log to the question. Thanks.

val credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(token, null))
.createScoped(DRIVE_SCOPES) with the accepted answer, this creates a problem with token refreshing...perhaps just in my code!
